# I think setcookie is not working

Tags: php

I'm new here so please bear with me.

I have this code:

```
<?php
include('connectDb.php');
$code = $conn->real_escape_string(utf8_encode(md5($_POST['code'])));
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE prs = '".$code."'")
        or trigger_error($conn->error);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);
if($result->num_rows < 1){
    echo 'wrong';
}else{
    session_start();
    session_destroy($_SESSION['continue']);
    session_unset($_SESSION['continue']);
    if(isset($_SESSION['cookie'])){
        setcookie("user", $row["usr"], 15778516381168);
    }else{
        $_SESSION['logIn'] = $row['usr'];
    }
}
```

Everything works except it won't create the cookie. 
Feel free to ask anything because I don't know what to tell you anymore.

Comment: The Expire value is too big. Use time()+60*60*24*14 for expire value or a time stamp with maximum digits 13.

Comment: Your time stamp is too big by an order of magnitude.  It should, at most, have 13 digits.  Yours has 14.  Oh, 14 seconds too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();
```

must be the first thing you have in your PHP page, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Almost: [_"To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called **before outputing anything to the browser**"_](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Comment: Yes, should have put it in a more professional way, but it's usually the easiest way to get it right, OP will get the point now for sure.

Comment: But there is nothing being echo'd before the `session_start()` or `setcookie()` calls, so this won't solve the issue.

Comment: I have now change the expire value to <code>time()+60*60*24*14</code> and moved <code>session_start()</code> top the top but it still won't create a cookie.